# Strange infinite recursion behavior with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, bluebird

I created a NodeJS program (with Bluebird as Promise library) that handles some validations similar to how the snippet below works, but if I run that script it throws the following error:

`Unhandled rejection RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Apparently, it's doing some recursive function call at the reassigning of the validations functions where I used `.bind(ctx)`

The way I solved that problem was assigning the Promise factory to `obj._validate` instead of reassigning `obj.validate` and use `_validate(ctx)` where it's needed.

But I still don't realize why that error happened. Can someone explain to me?

```js
// Example validation function
function validate(pass, fail) {
  const ctx = this
  Promise.resolve(ctx.value) // Simulate some async validation
    .then((value) => {
      if (value === 'pass') pass()
      if (value == 'fail') fail('Validation failed!')
    })
}

let validations = [
  {name: 'foo', validate: validate},
  {name: 'bar', validate: validate},
  {name: 'baz', validate: validate},
  {name: 'qux', validate: validate}
]

// Reassigning validate functions to a promise factory
// to handle async validation
validations.forEach(obj => {
  obj.validate = (ctx) => { // ctx used as context to validation
    return new Promise(obj.validate.bind(ctx))
  }
})

function executeValidations(receivedValues, validations) {
  receivedValues.forEach((obj, i) => {
    validations[i].validate(obj) // obj becomes the context to validate
      .then(() => console.log('Validation on', obj.name, 'passed'))
      .catch(e => console.error('Validation error on', obj.name, ':', e))
  })
}

let receivedValues1 = [
  {name: 'foo', value: 'pass'},
  {name: 'bar', value: 'fail'},
  {name: 'baz', value: 'fail'},
  {name: 'qux', value: 'pass'},
]

executeValidations(receivedValues1, validations)

let receivedValues2 = [
  {name: 'foo', value: 'pass'},
  {name: 'bar', value: 'pass'},
  {name: 'baz', value: 'fail'},
  {name: 'qux', value: 'fail'},
]

executeValidations(receivedValues2, validations)
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.4.7/bluebird.js"></script>
```

**EDIT: I think this is a short version of the problem**

```js
function fn(res, rej) { return this.foo }

fn = function(ctx) { return new Promise(fn.bind(ctx))}

const ctx = {foo: 'bar'}
fn(ctx)
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.4.7/bluebird.js"></script>
```

Comment: Leaving aside the promise constructor and `.bind()`, you are essentially doing `obj.validate = () => obj.validate()`. Of course that's infinite recursion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    obj.validate.bind(ctx)
```

evaluates to an exotic function object with its `this` value set to `ctx`. It is still, very much, a function object.

It then appears that

```
    obj.validate = (ctx) => { // ctx used as context to validation
    return new Promise(obj.validate.bind(ctx))
```

sets `obj.validate` to a function which returns a promise which during its construction *synchronously* calls its resolver function `obj.validate.bind(ctx)` (a.k.a. "executor function" in ES6) which returns a promise object whose construction synchronously calls `obj.validate.bind(ctx)`, and so on ad infinitum or the JavaScript engine throws an error.

Hence *calling* `obj.validate` a first time initiates an infinite loop of promise prodution by the resolver function.

**A further issue with `bind` usage:**

Arrow functions bind their lexical this value when declared. Syntactically `Function.prototype.bind` can be applied to an arrow function *but does not change the `this` value seen by the arrow function!*

Hence `obj.validate.bind(ctx)` never updates the `this` value seen within `obj.validate` if the method was defined using an arrow function.

---

Edit:

The biggest problem may be overwriting the value of the function which performs the operation:

As posted:

```
    validations.forEach(obj => {
      obj.validate = (ctx) => { // ctx used as context to validation
        return new Promise(obj.validate.bind(ctx))
      }
```

overwrites the `validate` property of each `validations` entry. This property used to be the named function `validate` declared at the start, but is no longer.

In the short version,

```
    function fn(res, rej) { return this.foo }

    fn = function(ctx) { return new Promise(fn.bind(ctx))}

    const ctx = {foo: 'bar'}
    fn(ctx)
```

`fn = function...` overwrites the named function declaration of `fn`. This means that when `fn` is called later, the `fn` of `fn.bind(ctx)` refers to the updated version of `fn`, not the original.

Note also that the resolver function must call its first function parameter (`resolve`) to synchronously resolve a new promise. Return values of the resolver function are ignored.

Comment: So when the Promise constructor executes, `obj.validate.bind(ctx)` is already a Promise factory?

The `obj.validate` assignment has to wait for the Promise construction end to change `obj.validate` value, doesn't it?

Comment: No to the second question. The `obj.validate` assignment occurs within a `forEach` iterator but does not _call_ the `obj.validate` method itself.  Yes to the first question: `obj.validate` creates a promise which calls `obj.validate` during construction.

Comment: I am aware of the lexical binding of arrow functions, but that issue doesn't affect this problem. See my `EDIT`.

Answer (score 0):

executeValidations() expects validate() to return a promise, so its better to return a promise.  Rejecting a promise is useful when something goes wrong during a validation, but failing a validation test is a normal part of the validation process, not an error.

```
// Example validation function
function validate(ctx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Perform validation asynchronously to fake some async operation
        process.nextTick(() => {
            // Passing validations resolve with undefined result
            if (ctx.value === 'pass') resolve()
            // Failing validations resolve with an error object
            if (ctx.value == 'fail') resolve({
                name: ctx.name,
                error: 'Validation failed!'
            })
            // Something went wrong
            reject('Error during validation')
        })
    })
}
```

Now executeValidations() can map the validations to a list of errors

```
function executeValidations(receivedValues, validations) {
    // Call validate for each received value, wait for the promises to resolve, then filter out any undefined (i.e. success) results
    return Promise.all(receivedValues.map( obj => validate(obj)))    
            .then(results => results.filter(o => o !== undefined))
}
```

The validations succeeded if there were no errors...

```
executeValidations(receivedValues1, validations)
.then (errors => {
    if (!errors.length)
        console.log('Validations passed')
    else
        errors.forEach(error => console.error(error))
})

executeValidations(receivedValues2, validations)
.then (errors => {
    if (!errors.length)
        console.log('Validations passed')
    else
        errors.forEach(error => console.error(error))
})
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Combining errors with validation fails is a bad thing. Thanks for that!